# Python syntax error ... not sure why

Tags: python, syntax

I've used a statement like the following before, however when I try using something similar it returns an error....

```
  File "test.py", line 73
    with open(hostsTxt, 'a+') as f1, open(hostsCSV,'a+') as f2, open(hostNameLook, 'a+') as f3, open(webHostsTxt,'a+') as f4:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Syntax with line above:

```
if hostName != "*" and hostIP != "*":
  with open(hostsTxt, 'a+') as f1, open(hostsCSV,'a+') as f2, open(hostNameLook, 'a+') as f3, open(webHostsTxt,'a+') as f4:
```

Any thoughts would be welcomed.

Comment: It could also be misplaced indentation or you forgot to use a tab instead of spaces.

Comment: Can you give a few more lines of context?

Comment: @squiguy: that *usually* leads to an `IndentationError` instead.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?  I'd guess 2.5.6 or earlier; I can match the error message (even down to the carat pointing at the "n" in open).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried both on Python 2.4 and 2.7 and it seems that same error happens on 2.4 and does not on 2.7

Python 2.4 - I did get the exact same error that you got.

```
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Nov  3 2010, 12:52:40) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> if hostName != "*" and hostIP != "*":
...   with open(hostsTxt, 'a+') as f1, open(hostsCSV,'a+') as f2, open(hostNameLook, 'a+') as f3, open(webHostsTxt,'a+') as f4:
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    with open(hostsTxt, 'a+') as f1, open(hostsCSV,'a+') as f2, open(hostNameLook, 'a+') as f3, open(webHostsTxt,'a+') as f4:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Python 2.7

```
Launching python -O
Python 2.7.2 (default, Apr 17 2012, 22:01:25) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> hostIP ='localhost'
>>> hostName = 'abcd'
>>> if hostName != "*" and hostIP != "*":
...   with open(hostsTxt, 'a+') as f1, open(hostsCSV,'a+') as f2, open(hostNameLook, 'a+') as f3, open(webHostsTxt,'a+') as f4:
...     print 'testing'
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'hostsTxt' is not defined
```

As far as I know, you are trying to use with open with python 2.4 which is not supported.

Comment: I think that might be it... There are two instances of python on the system (one is possibly 2.4, but def not 2.7). and the instance I normally use comes packaged with py2.7. I'll test this back at work

Comment: Yes this was the issue! Thanks very much. I will have to remember this when testing in future

Answer (score 7):

Look at the lines *before* it, there will be a parenthesis or bracket missing.

That, or you have a python version that doesn't support `with` at all, the syntax wasn't introduced until python 2.6.

Comment: This is the line (see edit above) context with the line before... I've looked up and down the script, i've not used tabs on double-spaces and checked the barckets and parenthesis as well...

Comment: Test for indentation with `python -tt scriptname.py`. Nothing obvious from that line, could be before that still.

Comment: it should be two-space indents

Comment: @MHibbin: Then it's not indentation that's the problem (though 2-space indents are in my opinion unreadable).